# Performing ST_Distance query in file geodatabase using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, sql, file-geodatabase, st-distance

I'm trying to create a view in ArcGIS Pro that joins attributes from two feature classes.  The features need to be joined by an ID field and by distance.  I want the features in the TABLE1_ERASE layer to be joined to TABLE1 by ID and distance.  The syntax for SQL Server is shown below but I'm running the queries in a local file geodatabase.  I've accomplished the task in ArcPy by setting query definitions (ID=1, ID=2, etc.) on both tables and spatially joining but that process is slow.  I'm really just looking for the Esri equivalent to SQL Server's ST_Distance function.

SQL Server Syntax

```sql
SELECT * from TABLE1_ERASE
LEFT JOIN TABLE1
ON TABLE1_ERASE.ID=TABLE1.ID
and TABLE1_ERASE.Shape.STDistance(TABLE1_.Shape) < 100;
```

Comment: There is no such function. File geodatabase is not an ISO-conformant RDBMS.

Comment: It sounds like iteration through search cursors may be the best way to join by location and attribute.  For others facing the same issue, I was able to join by multiple attributes (ID, distance) by: (1) running a search cursor to get all unique ID's, (2) iterate through list of ID's and setup query defs on my erase and LRS derived feature classes and (3) spatial join LRS derived layer to erase features.  Processing time for the script is roughly 17 minutes.

Comment: FYI - I've noticed that setting the arcpy environment variables arcpy.SetLogHistory() and  arcpy.SetLogMetadata() to false greatly reduces execution time.  Vince - thanks for the helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

Geometry function do not work on File GDB

Answer (score 0):

Although the existing answer and comments still stand, i.e., not possible with file geodatabases, it is worth pointing out this is possible with mobile geodatabases.  As support for mobile geodatabases improves across Esri's product lines, they are becoming more of an option when filesystem-based geodatabases are needed.

According to [Mobile geodatabases - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/manage-mobile-gdb/mobile-geodatabases.htm):

> Mobile geodatabases use the Esri ST_Geometry spatial type. Using a SQL
> client, you can access your spatial data through SQL statements that
> implement the ISO SQL/MM Spatial Standard and the Simple Feature
> Specification of the Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC). Having SQL
> access to the data allows you to use other applications to query or
> generate reports on data stored in a mobile geodatabase.

The ST_Geometry equivalent of the OP's query for a mobile geodatabase might be (*since data schema isn't given, there is some uncertainty around exact SQL that would work*):

```sql
SELECT * from TABLE1_ERASE
LEFT JOIN TABLE1
ON TABLE1_ERASE.ID=TABLE1.ID
and st_distance(TABLE1_ERASE.Shape, TABLE1.Shape) < 100;
```